# I get all the sql data but in the xml it is only one person what am I doing wrong

Tags: c#

Every time I run the code below it is supposed to come up with anyone with the name of "sam" in the database but it doesn't i just comes up with one person...

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(string name)
        {
            string PersonID;
            string PersonName;
            var info = new Person[] {};
            try
            {
                string connectionString =
                    @"Password=nottelling;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=nottelling;Initial Catalog=customers;Data Source=db.example.com;";
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string command = string.Format(@"SELECT Fname, PersonID, Lname FROM Person Where Fname = '{0}'",name);
                    connection.Open();
                    var getperson = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
                    SqlDataReader reader = getperson.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        PersonID = reader["PersonID"].ToString();
                        PersonName = reader["Fname"].ToString();
                        PersonName += " ";
                        PersonName += reader["Lname"].ToString();
                        info = new Person[] {new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName}};
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PersonID = "Error:";
                PersonName = ex.Message;
                info = new[] {new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName}};

            }
            return info;
        }
```

and Person is :

```
namespace Calculator.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The query works because I already tested it multiple times on another program.
I think the error is from :

```
info = new Person[] {new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName}};
```

because it replaces the whole value of info how would I not replace the whole value and just add to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As recommended by DanC,  I have changed the array type

You are assigning a brand new array each time... You should be adding to the array... Look at using something like the `ArrayList` class for ease of use

Instead of...

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(string name)
```

Change to...

```
public List<Person> GetPersons(string name)
```

Instead of...

```
var info = new Person[] {};
```

Change to...

```
List<Person> info = new List<Person>;
```

Instead of...

```
info = new Person[] {new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName}};
```

Change to...

```
info.Add(new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName});
```

Comment: @wizage see my updated answer, hopefully it makes sense... but as I say, I'm not sure whether the ToArray will take the type or not... been a while since I've been able to do any proper C# work

Comment: If you use a generic list such as List<Person> instead of the ArrayList you can avoid the info.ToArray in the return statement. Your new return statement would then be "return info;"

Comment: Good call @DanC, as I say, it's been a while since I've been able to get my teeth into C# - I will update my answer

Comment: Got an error: `At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.`

Comment: Oh just got @DanC comment I will try that

Comment: @wizage I have updated my answer to reflect the recommendation by DanC (don't forget to put the return back to just `return info;`)

Comment: @wizage - great to hear, and thanks to DanC for his suggestion

Comment: yep mvc 4 tutorials are hard to follow sometimes and sometimes make no sense for anything but what they do with that is why I like this forum because people can help you :D

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(string name)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Password=nottelling;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=nottelling;Initial Catalog=customers;Data Source=db.example.com;";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string command = string.Format(@"SELECT Fname, PersonID, Lname FROM Person Where Fname = '{0}'", name);
            connection.Open();

            using (var getperson = new SqlCommand(command, connection))
            using (var reader = getperson.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string PersonID = reader["PersonID"].ToString();
                    string PersonName = reader["Fname"].ToString();
                    PersonName += " ";
                    PersonName += reader["Lname"].ToString();
                    yield return new Person {PersonId = PersonID, Name = PersonName};
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I ripped out that terrible exception handling. Added yield return so you don't have to build an intermediate list. You can .ToList() or .ToArray() or whatever at the call site. Added the appropriate using statements to disppose your other objects. Removed redundant connection close.

Plus you should really be using parameterized queries instead of string substitution because that code is vulnerable to sql injection, but I'll leave some work for you. :D

Comment: This not final code I am waiting to do sql injection security this is just for test mvc 4